# newline character left in the cin.get() buffer

Tags: c++, cin

I am using `cin.get(input).ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` in my code. this statement is being called in a while loop to choose an option in a menu.
Although I am using ignore chained with `cin.get()` for every input I am reading in, sometimes a newline character remains in the cin buffer and I should press an extra 'Enter' to go to the normal process of the while loop for choosing an option.
what should I do to solve this problem?

```
int Menu::getChoice(int menuNum)    // getChoice() returns users menu choice
{
    int i = 0;
    char input;
    while(0 == i)       // As long as users choice not valid
    {
        cout << "Make your choice: ";
        cin.get(input).ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        if (!cin.good())
        {
            cin.clear();                    
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');  
        }
        i = atoi(&input);
        if (menuNum == 1)
        {
            if (i < 1 || i > 2)
            {
                cout << "Not a valid choice!" << endl;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: So if `cin` is in a bad state, you ignore input again. That would do it. And why are you using `atoi` at all, let alone with a non-null-terminated string? Use `input - '0'` and check if `std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(input))`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this issue is that sometimes in order for the code to move past cin, and to get the assignment for input, two new line characters are needed. If this is correct, than if you replace:

```
cin.get(input).ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

with this:

```
cin >> input;
```

the issue will be resolved.